# Latex Tikz drawing loop diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, labels

I am new to tikz and I wanted to draw a surface with this loop on latex but I don't know how to insert the labels or even properly drawing the curves. Do you have any suggestions on where to start or a similar diagram I could base myself on? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE. Do be able to help you more, I suggest you add a minimal working example to your question showing us, what you have already tried. At this point, there is no real question to answer and I'd refer you to the tutorial of the tikz/pgf manual, which should cover the basics of what you need to re-draw this image.

Comment: Thank you! At this point I have only done a rough hand drawn diagram. I am trying to learn tikz properly!

Comment: I can appreciate your thought and I understand that learning tikz from zero is very daunting in the beginning. However, there are actually many questions here on tex.SE concerning tikz, which have excellent answers that will surely help you out. E.g. have a look at this recent one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592944/118712 . If you still have some more specific question, feel free to edit your question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using `tkz-euclide` to be able to draw some real arcs.

[image: spherical surface?]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
        \def\larg{3} \def\long{5} \def\xshft{1} \def\yshft{1}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (\long,\yshft);
        \coordinate (C) at (\long+\xshft,\larg+\yshft);
        \coordinate (D) at (\xshft,\larg);
        
        % Radii of the arcs (for lines and arrows)
        \def\rada{12} \def\radb{18}
        \def\radaa{12.3} \def\radab{11.7}
        \def\radba{18.3} \def\radbb{17.7}
        
        % Arc between A and D
        \tkzInterCC[R](A,\rada cm)(D,\rada cm) \tkzGetSecondPoint{H1}
        \tkzDrawArc[angles,line width=.75pt](H1,D)(150,174)
        
        % Arrow from D to A
        \tkzDrawArc[R,very thick,color=orange,->](H1,\radaa cm)(158,168)
        
        % Arc between B and C
        \tkzInterCC[R](B,\rada cm)(C,\rada cm) \tkzGetSecondPoint{H2}
        \tkzDrawArc[angles,line width=.75pt](H2,C)(150,174)
        
        % Arrow from B to C
        \tkzDrawArc[R,very thick,color=orange,<-](H2,\radab cm)(156,166)
        
        % Arc between A and B
        \tkzInterCC[R](A,\radb cm)(B,\radb cm) \tkzGetSecondPoint{H3}
        \tkzDrawArc[angles,line width=.75pt](H3,A)(90,112)
        
        % Arrow from A to B
        \tkzDrawArc[R,very thick,color=orange,<-](H3,\radbb cm)(95,108)
        
        % Arc between D and C
        \tkzInterCC[R](D,\radb cm)(C,\radb cm) \tkzGetSecondPoint{H4}
        \tkzDrawArc[angles,line width=.75pt](H4,D)(90,113)
        
        % Arrow from D to C
        \tkzDrawArc[R,very thick,color=orange,->](H4,\radba cm)(94,107)
        
        
        % Points and figures
        \foreach \p in {A,B,C,D} \filldraw (\p) circle (1pt) node[below right] {\p};
        \node[left] at (-0.7,-0.3) {$x^2=0$};
        \node[left] at (0,2.7) {$x^2=\delta b$};
        \node[below] at (-0.2,-.9) {$x^1=0$};
        \node[below] at (4.8,0.1) {$x^1=\delta a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I give it a try. The result looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % define nodes
        \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B1) at ($ (A1) + (5,1) $);
        \coordinate (C1) at ($ (B1) + (1,5) $);
        \coordinate (D1) at ($ (A1) + (1,5) $);
        
        \draw (A1) node {$ \bullet $} node[below=5pt] {A1};
        \draw (B1) node {$ \bullet $} node[below=5pt] {B1};
        \draw (C1) node {$ \bullet $} node[above=5pt] {C1};
        \draw (D1) node {$ \bullet $} node[above=5pt] {D1};
        
        \coordinate (A2) at ($ (A1) + (-1,1) $);
        \coordinate (B2) at ($ (B1) + (1,1) $);
        \coordinate (C2) at ($ (C1) + (1,-1) $);
        \coordinate (D2) at ($ (D1) + (-1,-1) $);
        
        \draw (A2) node {$ \bullet $} node[below=5pt] {A2};
        \draw (B2) node {$ \bullet $} node[below=5pt] {B2};
        \draw (C2) node {$ \bullet $} node[above=5pt] {C2};
        \draw (D2) node {$ \bullet $} node[above=5pt] {D2};
        
        % draw lines
        
        \draw[name path=AB] (A2) to[bend left=10] (B2);
        \draw[name path=AD] (A1) to[bend left=10] (D1);
        \draw[name path=DC] (D2) to[bend left=10] (C2);
        \draw[name path=BC] (B1) to[bend left=10] (C1);
        
        % calculate intersections
        
        \path[name intersections={of=AB and AD},];
        \draw (intersection-1) node(A) {$ \bullet $} node[below right] {A};
        
        \path[name intersections={of=AB and BC},];
        \draw (intersection-1) node(B) {$ \bullet $} node[below right] {B};
        
        \path[name intersections={of=BC and DC},];
        \draw (intersection-1) node(C) {$ \bullet $} node[below right] {C};
        
        \path[name intersections={of=AD and DC},];
        \draw (intersection-1) node(D) {$ \bullet $} node[below right] {D};
        
        % draw arrows
        
        \draw[-stealth,bend left=10,shorten >=0.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm,lightgray,thick] ($ (A) + (0,-0.5) $) to ($ (B) + (0,-0.5) $);
        \draw[-stealth,bend left=10,shorten >=0.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm,lightgray,thick] ($ (B) + (0.5,0) $) to ($ (C) + (0.5,0) $);
        \draw[-stealth,bend right=10,shorten >=0.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm, lightgray,thick] ($ (C) + (0,0.5) $) to ($ (D) + (0,0.5) $);
        \draw[-stealth,bend right=10,shorten >=0.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm,lightgray,thick] ($ (D) + (-0.5,0) $) to ($ (A) + (-0.5,0) $);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First, you define the coordinates for the start and end point of the line (A1/2-D1/2). Therefore, I used the `calc` library, where you can a.o., set the distance of points unsing `($(startpoint) + (xshift,ysift)$)`. Then, you draw the lines between the points. Here, I added a bending of the line using `(point1) to[bend left=...] (point2)` and connected all points.
The syntax `name path` is used to compute the intersection of the lines using `intersections` library, where the first intersections `(intersection-1)` are labeled.
The last step is drawing the arrows between these points (with respective offset) using `\draw[-stealth,bend left=...] (point1) to (point2)`.

Hopefully you get an idea how it works.

Your task now is changing the labels for the nodes of the graph (change the input in `node[...] {change name here}`), since I kept them for better understanding of the workflow, and maybe adjust the offset of the arrows regarding your needs. Therefore, you can play around with the `shorten >=...` and `shorten <=...` arguments in the `\draw` environment and the coordinates for the shift of the nodes.

Comment: @Miug14 I changed the code a bit for a better look of the result.

Comment: Thank you for the code and the clear explanation! I am looking forward to learning all the commands!